# Delete table rows if column value contains a string similar to a column value from another table

Tags: mysql

I have two different tables, **table_foo** and **table_bar**. I want to delete rows in **table_foo** if a column consists a string from **table_bar**

**table_bar**

```
     bar_id      |    address    |  stat_id  |
-----------------+---------------+-----------+
  COMM_14.15.7   |     12345     |     1     |
  COMM_13.03.9   |     78543     |     2     |
```

**table_foo**

```
         comm_id         |    managed    |
-------------------------+---------------+
  COMM_11.21.6_enabled   |     true      |
  COMM_14.15.7_enabled   |     true      |
  COMM_13.03.9_enabled   |     true      |
```

In this example, 2 rows in **table_foo** will be removed since bar_id value *COMM_14.15.7* is in comm_id value **COMM_14.15.7**_enabled.

What I have tried so far is this query:

```
DELETE FROM table_foo tf
USING table_bar tn
WHERE fsj.comm_id LIKE tn.bar_id;
```

I used the LIKE command but in this example, it didn't not work. There's also no syntax error. Any advice and ideas regarding this is highly appreciated.

Comment: You miss the `%` sign in like expression

Answer (score 0):

You need to use wildcard(s) with your `LIKE` expression. For example, if you are looking for matches where `comm_id` starts with `bar_id`, something like this should work for you:

```
DELETE table_foo.*
FROM table_foo
INNER JOIN table_bar on table_bar.comm_id LIKE concat(table_foo.bar_id,'%');
```